# Program to determine ranges of char, short, int and long variables, both signed and unsigned

Tags: beginner, c, integer

I wrote code to determinate ranges of char,short int and long variables,both signed and unsigned.Please help me to improve my code :) Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function declerations...
long power(int base, int power);

int main(void) {
    //From 2^(N-1) to 2^(N-1)-1 (Two's complement)
    int intmin = power(2, sizeof(int) * 8 - 1);
    int intmax = power(2, sizeof(int) * 8 - 1) - 1;
    unsigned unsignedintmax = power(2, sizeof(int) * 8) - 1;
    char minchar = -(power(2, sizeof(char) * 8 - 1));
    char maxchar = power(2, sizeof(char) * 8 - 1) - 1;
    unsigned char unsignedcharmax = power(2, sizeof(char) * 8) - 1;
    short shortmin = -(power(2, sizeof(short) * 8 - 1));
    short shortmax = power(2, sizeof(short) * 8 - 1) - 1;
    unsigned short unsignedshortmax = power(2, sizeof(short) * 8) - 1;
    long minlong = power(2, sizeof(long) * 8 - 1);
    long maxlong = power(2, sizeof(long) * 8 - 1) - 1;
    unsigned long unsignedlongmax = power(2, sizeof(long) * 8) - 1;
    minlong*=-1;
    printf("\nSigned char can be minimum: %d and maximum: %d\n", minchar, maxchar);
    printf("\nUnsigned char can be minimum: %d and maximum: %u\n", 0, unsignedcharmax);
    printf("\nSigned short can be minimum: %d and maximum: %d\n", shortmin, shortmax);
    printf("\nUnsigned short can be minimum: %d and maximum: %u\n", 0, unsignedshortmax);
    printf("\nSigned int can be minimum: %d and maximum: %d\n", intmin, intmax);
    printf("\nUnsigned int can be minimum: %d and maximum: %u\n", 0, unsignedintmax);
    printf("\nSigned long can be minimum: %ld and maximum: %ld\n", minlong, maxlong);
    printf("\nUnsigned long can be minimum: %d and maximum: %lu\n\n", 0, unsignedlongmax);

    return 0;
}

long power(int base, int power) {
    long pf = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        pf *= base;
    }
    return pf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Signedness of unqualified `char` is implementation defined. It may well be possible that `char` is in fact unsigned. Change `char` to `signed char`.
- A char is not guaranteed to have 8 bits (it is guaranteed to have *at least* 8 bits). Use `CHAR_BIT` instead.
- Narrowing types (e.g. assigning `long` to `char`) always make me uncomfortable. A better technique to get a value with only MSB set is (`TYPE` is either `char,int,long,whatever`)

  ```
  unsigned TYPE value = ~(((unsigned TYPE) -1) >> 1)
  ```

Comment: I just don't understand why is char not guaranteed to be 8 bits.Because as i know it **must** be 8 bits.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak, you're wrong.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) hosted small reference page for your question.

Comment: i have worked on computers where char is 7 bits, where null is 0xffffffff. C deals with all sorts of types of machine

Comment: Than how ASCII Code works ?? I mean its not 255 but 127 ??

Comment: @MuhamedCicak Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char